# About a norm of $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable function.

$a, b \in U$,
$L := \{a + t (b - a) \mid t \in [0, 1]\} \subset U$,
$|A| := \left(\sum_{i = 1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{i j}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Does $\{|f'(x)| \mid x \in L\}$ have an upper bound?

Comment: Try the case $m=1$, $n=1$, $U=(-1,1)$, $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$, $f(0)=0$, $a=0$, and $b=1/2$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(2*x*sin(1%2Fx)+-+cos(1%2Fx))+from+x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+1%2F2

Comment: Thank you nextpuzzle. I think $f$ has an upper bound.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to increase the exponents. Replace it with $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$.